# Remove all spaces for chinese characters while keeping necessary spaces for english in Python regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, python-re

Let's say my dataframe has column which is mixed with english and chinese words or characters, I would like to remove all the whitespaces between them if they're chinese words, otherwise if they're english, then keep one space only between words:

I have found a solution for removing extra spaces between english from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419940/how-to-remove-spaces-in-between-characters-without-removing-all-spaces-in-a-data)

```
import re
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['V e  r y calm', 'Keen and a n a l y t i c a l',
'R a s h and careless', 'Always joyful', '你 好', '黑 石  公 司', 'FAN     STUD1O', 'beauty face 店  铺'])
```

Code:

```
regex = re.compile('(?<![a-zA-Z]{2})(?<=[a-zA-Z]{1}) +(?=[a-zA-Z] |.$)')
s.str.replace(regex, '')
```

Out:

```
Out[87]: 
0              Very calm
1    Keen and analytical
2      Rash and careless
3          Always joyful
4                    你 好
5               黑 石  公 司
dtype: object
```

But as you see, it works out for english but didn't remove spaces between chinese, how could get an expected result as follows:

```
Out[87]: 
0              Very calm
1    Keen and analytical
2      Rash and careless
3          Always joyful
4                    你好
5                 黑石公司
dtype: object
```

Reference: [Remove all spaces between Chinese words with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179179/remove-all-spaces-between-chinese-words-with-regex)

Comment: What about single-letter words `"a"` and `"I"`?

Comment: Thanks, guys. Lot's of good options.

Comment: That's a good question @Bohemian, in some rare cases, for example `X Y Z company`, the only one space should be removed and get `XYZ company` in fact, but I've no idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: I've updated new elements for serie `s`, it seems none of your solution work out as it's mixture of english and chinese. Could someone help to test again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should get you what you want. See the full code snippet at the bottom.

```
regex = re.compile(
    "((?<![a-zA-Z]{2})(?<=[a-zA-Z]{1})\s+(?=[a-zA-Z]\s|.$)|(?<=[\u4e00-\u9fff]{1})\s+)",
    re.UNICODE,
)
```

I made the following edits to your regex above:
Right now, the regex basically matches all spaces that appear after a single-letter word and before another single character word.

1. I added a part at the end of the regex that would select all spaces after a Chinese character (I used the unicode range `[\u4e00-\u9fff]` which would cover Japanese and Korean as well.
2. I changed the spaces in the regex to the whitespace character class `\s` so we could catch other input like tabs.
3. I also added the `re.UNICODE` flag so that `\s` would cover unicode spaces as well.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(
    [
        "V e  r y calm",
        "Keen and a n a l y t i c a l",
        "R a s h and careless",
        "Always joyful",
        "你 好",
        "黑 石  公 司",
    ]
)

regex = re.compile(
    "((?<![a-zA-Z]{2})(?<=[a-zA-Z]{1})\s+(?=[a-zA-Z]\s|.$)|(?<=[\u4e00-\u9fff]{1})\s+)",
    re.UNICODE,
)
s.str.replace(regex, "")
```

Output:

```
0              Very calm
1    Keen and analytical
2      Rash and careless
3          Always joyful
4                     你好
5                   黑石公司
dtype: object
```

Comment: Sorry, your solution seem not working for `FAN     STUD1O`, I think maybe we need to `df['Day'].str.capitalize()` then apply your code?

Comment: I would handle that case with a simpler regex that combines all spaces in a string
`s.str.replace(re.compile("\s+", re.UNICODE), " ")`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Chinese (well, CJK) [Unicode property](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Categories) `\p{script=Han}` or `\p{Han}`.
However, this only works if the regex engine supports UTS#18 Unicode regular expressions. The default Python re module does not but you can use the alternative (much improved) [regex engine](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```
import regex as re

rex = r"(?<![a-zA-Z]{2})(?<=[a-zA-Z]{1})[ ]+(?=[a-zA-Z] |.$)|(?<=\p{Han}) +"
test_str = ("V e  r y calm\n"
    "Keen and a n a l y t i c a l\n"
    "R a s h and careless\n"
    "Always joyful\n"
    "你 好\n"
    "黑 石  公 司")
result = re.sub(rex, "", test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE)
```

Results in

> ```
> Very calm
> Keen and analytical
> Rash and careless
> Always joyful
> 你好
> 黑石公司
> ```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZzoEv/1) (the demo is using PCRE for demonstration purposes only)

Comment: I apply your code to one column `rent_name`, using `df['rent_name'].replace(re.compile(r"(?<![a-zA-Z]{2})(?<=[a-zA-Z]{1})[ ]+(?=[a-zA-Z] |.$)|(?<=\p{Han}) +", re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE))`, it returns `error: bad escape \p`, any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `import regex as re`?

Comment: Yes, it raises an error: `TypeError: replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'repl'`. If `test_str` is one column in dataframe, how could I use your code?

Answer (score 2):

Use word boundaries `\b` in look arounds:

```
(?<=\b\w\b) +(?=\b\w\b)
```

This matches spaces between solitary (bounded by word boundaries) "word characters", which includes Chinese characters.

Pre python 3 (and for java for example), `\w` only matches English letters, so you would need to add the *unicode* flag `(?u)` to the front of the regex.

---

```
s = ['V e  r y calm', 'Keen and a n a l y t i c a l',
'R a s h and careless', 'Always joyful', '你 好', '黑 石  公 司']
regex = r'(?<=\b\w\b) +(?=\b\w\b)'
res = [re.sub(regex, '', line) for line in s]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['Very calm', 'Keen and analytical', 'Rash and careless', 'Always joyful', '你好', '黑石公司']
```

Comment: Why do you need `(?u)`? It is on by default in Python 3.x.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn’t know that. I’m a python newbie. Answer simplified and note made re python version. Thx